# EF Core seeding error: The seed entity for entity type 'X2' cannot be added because it has the navigation 'Y1' set

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an issue with **seeding database using Entity Framework**, code first approach.
Entity Framework Core + ASP.Net Core MVC

> The seed entity for entity type '**DentalHygienist**' cannot be added
> **because it has the navigation 'User' set. To seed relationships**,  add
> the entity seed to 'MedicalWorker' and specify the foreign key values
> {'UserId'}. Consider using
> 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the
> involved property values.

involved models:

```
 public abstract class MedicalWorker 
 {
        public MedicalWorker(Person person)
        {
            Person = person;
        }
        public MedicalWorker(long personId)
        {
            PersonId = personId;
        }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Required]

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long PersonId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public string ProfessionalNumber {get;set;}
    [NotMapped]
    public List<long> MedicalServiceIds { get; set; }
    public virtual List<MedicalService> MedicalServices { get; set; }
}

public class DentalHygienist : MedicalWorker
{

public DentalHygienist(long personId, string professionalNumber) : base(personId)
{
    ProfessionalNumber = professionalNumber;
    MedicalWorkerType = Enums.MedicalWorkerType.DentalHygienist;
    PersonId = personId;
}
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Required]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            PatientMockDB.SetData();
            modelBuilder.Entity<MedicalService>().HasData(PatientMockDB.MedicalServices);

            modelBuilder.Entity<MedicalWorker>()
            .HasDiscriminator<string>("Discriminator")
            .HasValue<Doctor>("1")
            .HasValue<Nurse>("2")
            .HasValue<ElectroradiologyTechnician>("3")
            .HasValue<DentalHygienist>("4")
            .HasValue<Physiotherapist>("5");

            modelBuilder.Entity<MedicalWorker>()
                .HasMany<MedicalService>(a => a.MedicalServices)                ;
            modelBuilder.Entity<MedicalWorker>()
                .HasOne<User>(c=>c.User)
                ;

        modelBuilder.Entity<Doctor>().HasData(PatientMockDB.MedicalWorkers.OfType<Doctor>());
        modelBuilder.Entity<Nurse>().HasData(PatientMockDB.MedicalWorkers.OfType<Nurse>());
        modelBuilder.Entity<ElectroradiologyTechnician>().HasData(PatientMockDB.MedicalWorkers.OfType<ElectroradiologyTechnician>());
        modelBuilder.Entity<DentalHygienist>().HasData(PatientMockDB.MedicalWorkers.OfType<DentalHygienist>());
        modelBuilder.Entity<Physiotherapist>().HasData(PatientMockDB.MedicalWorkers.OfType<Physiotherapist>());

..
.
..
.
}
```

Seeding with:

```
    new List<MedicalWorker>()
    {
        new Doctor(Persons[0].Id,"IUHIDUASHDI545613216")
        {
            Id=++id,
            UserId=Users[userId].Id,
            User=Users[userId++],
            Education=UM_1,
            HiredSince=new DateTime(2015,1,1),
            IsCurrentlyHired=true,
    VisitReviews=visitRatings1,
            MedicalServices=new List<MedicalService>()
            {
                PrimaryMedicalServices[0],PrimaryMedicalServices[1]
            }

        },
            new DentalHygienist(Persons[33].Id,"HASDUQ561613")
            {
                Id = ++id,
                                                    User=Users[userId++],
                UserId=Users[userId].Id,

                Education =UM_1,
                HiredSince=new DateTime(2015,10,1),
                IsCurrentlyHired=true,VisitReviews=visitRatings1,
                MedicalServices=new List<MedicalService>()
                {
                    PrimaryMedicalServices[25]
                }

            },
.
.
.
.
.
.
    };
```

As you can see I have no reference from User class to MedicalWorker/DentalHygienist, because I just want it to be one-way reference.

User could be referenced by multiple other classes and there might be no reference to MedicalWorker, but for example to Patient. So the relation between MedicalWorker and User is 0 or 1 to 1. And User have several such relations with other classes (1 to 0 or 1).

**Is there possiblity to implement one-way navigation** from different classes to User, without defining it in User class?

EDIT: thanks to @Ivan Stoev, Main issue that I have is with seeding entities that are inheriting from MedicalWorker.
Not sure how  should I *"specify the foreign key values {'UserId'}."*
Data that I am trying to seed contains UserId's.

Should I change definition of that relation in modelBuilder? If yes: how?

Comment: The problem is not the navigation (of course you can have "one-way"). The error is referring to `User` **property** of `MedicalWorker` derived class during **data seeding**.  In other words, some `HasData` call not shown here.

Comment: You are right, I read it without appropriate attention.

Comment: You only have to specify `MedicalWorker.UserId` which from what I see can simply be done by `UserId= userId`, or *maybe* `UserId=Users[userId].Id`, but you must remove `User=Users[userId++]`.